# restorePreviousSignIn() does not fetch a new idToken on expiring with GIDSignIn-iOS SDK V6.0.2

Tags: ios, google-oauth, google-signin, gidsignin

I have implemented a Google Sign in flow to my iOS.
First login works perfectly but after 1 hour when the idToken provided by Google expires, the restorePreviousSignIn() method is called but returns the same idToken. Can someone post an implementation of the restorePreviousSignIn() method

My restorePreviousSignIn() method looks as below-

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.restorePreviousSignIn { user, error in

    if error != nil || user == nil {
       print("Could not sign in user previously.\nError: \(String(describing: error))")
    }
    else {
    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.restorePreviousSignIn { user, error in
    if error != nil || user == nil {
        // Prompt the user to sign in again
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn()
    } else {
        if let auth = user.authentication {
            if auth.accessTokenExpirationDate.timeIntervalSinceNow < 0 {
                // Access token has expired, refresh the token
                auth.refreshToken { refreshedAuth, error in
                    if error != nil || refreshedAuth == nil {
                        // Refresh failed, prompt the user to sign in again
                        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn()
                    } else {
                        // Refresh succeeded, update the user's authentication object
                        user.authentication = refreshedAuth
                        // Use the refreshed idToken to authenticate the user
                        // Your code here
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // Access token is still valid, use the existing idToken to authenticate the user
                // Your code here
            }
        } else {
            // Prompt the user to sign in again
            GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way i dont have to signOut the user when the token has expired?  We dont want the user to relogin every hour

Comment: hmm yes you can use Google's token refresh mechanism to get a new access token without requiring the user to sign in again. I edited my original answer to reflect this,